# Finding the IP Table settings

Tags: iptables, firewall

Following the recommendations from the BasicSecurity manual, I enabled the ufw firewall (sudo ufw enable) "without further tweaks." I'd like to know what the default IP table settings look like, but don't know how to find them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can list all `iptables` rule settings by the `-L` (`--list`) option of `iptables`:

```
sudo iptables -L
```

For more verbosity, add `-v`:

```
sudo iptables -vL
```

For not to do name resolution (only numeric output), add -`n`:

```
sudo iptables -nvL
```

---

Note that, by default it will list only `filter` table entries, for other tables you need to explicitly mention the table type using `-t` (`--table`) option, e.g. for `nat` table:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -nvL
```

---

Also check `man iptables` to get more idea.

Answer (score 2):

Read `man iptables`. Then do something like:

```
for table in filter nat mangle raw security ; do
    sudo iptables -t $table -L | tee iptables.$table
done
```

(also leaves a copy in `iptables.{filter,nat,mangle,security}`